# how can I show a lot of image efficiently like instagram feed screen in react native?

Tags: react-native, instagram

I'm cloning instagram feed page.

I'm done implementing showing multiple image by each post.

but it takes a lot of memory because of a lot of images. now it's too slow when I load more and more images.

but on instagram, it never looks slow when I go down and down while loading a bunch of images.

how can I implement that?

Comment: You can use something like react-native-fast-image (https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image), in fact they have an Instagram style feed recording in the README.

Comment: @Dan thanks for answering. I'm already using fast image but it's sill slow with flatlist. is it  related to flatlist?

Comment: It could be, I've used https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview in the past which I found to be highly performant with react-native-fast-image.